# Python Curve Smoothing using Savitzky_Golay - issue

Tags: python, curve-fitting

[Input File CSV data link](https://github.com/GitHubAjoy/CurveFitting/blob/master/Vicky.csv).  My Python code is as pasted beneath. The curve smoothing technique does not really seem to be working. As I plot the smoothed curve upon the parent data, they overlap exactly. Could someone please help me in resolving the issue please. The code uses the `Savitzky_Golay` algorithm.The code extracts the `x`,`y` axis data from a `csv` file and is formulated to suite the required data type needed for the `Savitzky_Golay` function call
[image]

```
    import numpy as np
    import csv
    from math import factorial
    import itertools
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
    #from scipy.interpolate import spline
    #import openpyxl
    #import pandas as pd
    #from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


    def savitzky_golay(y, window_size, order, deriv=0, rate=1):
        r"""Smooth (and optionally differentiate) data with a Savitzky-Golay filter.
        The Savitzky-Golay filter removes high frequency noise from data.
        It has the advantage of preserving the original shape and
        features of the signal better than other types of filtering
        approaches, such as moving averages techniques.
        Parameters
        ----------
        y : array_like, shape (N,)
          the values of the time history of the signal.
        window_size : int
          the length of the window. Must be an odd integer number.
        order : int
          the order of the polynomial used in the filtering.
          Must be less then `window_size` - 1.
        deriv: int
          the order of the derivative to compute (default = 0 means only smoothing)
        Returns
        -------
        ys : ndarray, shape (N)
          the smoothed signal (or it's n-th derivative).
        Notes
        -----
        The Savitzky-Golay is a type of low-pass filter, particularly
        suited for smoothing noisy data. The main idea behind this
        approach is to make for each point a least-square fit with a
        polynomial of high order over a odd-sized window centered at
        the point.
        Examples
        --------
        t = np.linspace(-4, 4, 500)
        y = np.exp( -t**2 ) + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, t.shape)
        ysg = savitzky_golay(y, window_size=31, order=4)
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        plt.plot(t, y, label='Noisy signal')
        plt.plot(t, np.exp(-t**2), 'k', lw=1.5, label='Original signal')
        plt.plot(t, ysg, 'r', label='Filtered signal')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
        References
        ----------
        .. [1] A. Savitzky, M. J. E. Golay, Smoothing and Differentiation of
         Data by Simplified Least Squares Procedures. Analytical
         Chemistry, 1964, 36 (8), pp 1627-1639.
        .. [2] Numerical Recipes 3rd Edition: The Art of Scientific Computing
         W.H. Press, S.A. Teukolsky, W.T. Vetterling, B.P. Flannery
         Cambridge University Press ISBN-13: 9780521880688
        """

        try:
          window_size = np.abs(np.int(window_size))
          order = np.abs(np.int(order))
        except ValueError, msg:
          raise ValueError("window_size and order have to be of type int")
        if window_size % 2 != 1 or window_size < 1:
          raise TypeError("window_size size must be a positive odd number")
        if window_size < order + 2:
          raise TypeError("window_size is too small for the polynomials order")
        order_range = range(order+1)
        half_window = (window_size -1) // 2
        # precompute coefficients
        b = np.mat([[k**i for i in order_range] for k in range(-half_window, half_window+1)])
        m = np.linalg.pinv(b).A[deriv] * rate**deriv * factorial(deriv)
        # pad the signal at the extremes with
        # values taken from the signal itself
        firstvals = y[0] - np.abs( y[1:half_window+1][::-1] - y[0] )
        lastvals = y[-1] + np.abs(y[-half_window-1:-1][::-1] - y[-1])
        y = np.concatenate((firstvals, y, lastvals))
        return np.convolve( m[::-1], y, mode='valid')


    CurveName_1 = "Actual"
    ind1, ind2 = 0,0
    check = 0
    for line in open('C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\FileTransfers\Vicky.csv'):
        csv_row = line.split(",")
        csv_row = map(str.strip, csv_row)
        csv_row = [i.replace('"', '') for i in csv_row]
        if CurveName_1 in csv_row:
            ind1 = csv_row.index(CurveName_1)
            check += 1
        if check > 1:
            break

    x = []
    y = []
    with open( 'C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\FileTransfers\Vicky.csv', "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for idx,line in enumerate(reader):
            if idx>3:
                x.append(float(line[ind1]))
                y.append(float(line[0]))
                #t=line[ind1],line[ind2]
                #print t

    print len(x)
    print len(y)

    xm = np.array(x)
    ym = np.array(y)

    #ym = np.array(ym)
    yhat = savitzky_golay(ym, 51, 3) # window size 51, polynomial order 3

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.minorticks_on()
    # Customize the major grid
    plt.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='red')
    # Customize the minor grid
    plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
    axes = plt.subplot(111)
    axes.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))
    axes.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))
    plt.plot(yhat, xm)
    plt.plot(ym,xm, color='red')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: No please dont downgrade my question please.

Comment: Please post a link to the CSV data file.

Comment: Dear James, please help me as to how can I post the CSV data here. The CSV data is pretty huge, but I would really like to share it with you please. May I know your email id, that I may mail it to you please. I feel happy to have received your interest as I see you've got real good trouble shooting knowledge with curve fitting. Thank you so much James. I would like to honor your participation with an upgrade, but its not allowing me :(

Comment: Hi James, I have posted a link for the csv data. Kindly use the file for checking the problem , please. Highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: OK, I will try the code with your data file.

Comment: I see that you code is from the scipy example, but I do not see why the code is not working. My apologies.

Comment: Thats Okay James, thanks for the effort. Appreciate your help. Thank you James

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, and maybe not the exact answer to your question, but for a very similar application I use [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) to import the data and [`scipy.signal.savgol_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html#scipy-signal-savgol-filter) for filtering: the less I implement, the more chances it has of working properly...